# Where is this gorge?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, morocco

While preparing a cycle tour in Morocco, I saw [this point on google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@31.3599614,-5.2850714,3a,75y,106.66h,89.51t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-L3jVT2WkHN4%2FVm8ajgCMI_I%2FAAAAAAAAB4E%2Ffvp9Mloe8iIJTtcVOLm6Z_RpiSvT4Z4xgCJkC!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2F-L3jVT2WkHN4%2FVm8ajgCMI_I%2FAAAAAAAAB4E%2Ffvp9Mloe8iIJTtcVOLm6Z_RpiSvT4Z4xgCJkC%2Fw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya190.52007-ro-0-fo100%2F!7i9728!8i4864) :

[image]

But it seems to be placed on a bad location on the map. Can someone tell me where is it located, as I'd love to go there by bike?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems to be one of the [Dadès Gorges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dad%C3%A8s_Gorges); the road in the first picture in the gallery on Wikipedia matches yours.

[image]

<sub>By Rosino - flickr.com, CC BY-SA 2.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1038272</sub>

Answer (score 9):

It is the [Dadès Gorge](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=morocco+gorge+dades&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=31453214,-5967587,0). It is about six hours from Marrakech on the road to the dunes of Merzouga.

The [Auberge Chez Pierre](http://chezpierre.org/) is a convenient hotel nearby.

Comment: The hotel is way above my budget, but thanks anyway. I prefer wild camping.

Comment: Six hours cycling (as the question indicated) or by car? Wouldn't a distance be more useful here?

Comment: That would be by car.

Answer (score 0):

This is Dades Gorge, Located about 4 hours drive from Marrakech and there is another gorge called Todgha Gorge located 50km from this one.

It is a place where Cadillac also

Comment: Welcome to [travel.se]! Please consider finishing your answer...